# Show the preview of video selected from input type="file" in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

hey guys i need to add video to my server so before adding it to the server what i want is i need to show the preview of video selected by the user on client side in html video tag.

What i am doing is for now i am using a component which is like

CustomFileUpload.js

```
import React from "react";

const CustomFileUpload = (props) => (
  <div className="custom-file mb-3">
    <input type="file" className="custom-file-input" onChange={props.onChange}id="customFile2" />
    <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile2">
      {props.value == null ? 'Choose File...' : props.value.name}
    </label>
  </div>
);

export default CustomFileUpload;
```

and then in my another component i am importing it and using like

```
<CustomFileUpload
                          value={this.state.video}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            this.setState(
                              {
                                video: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
                              },
                              () => console.log(this.state.video)
                            )
                          }
                        />
                        {this.state.video != null ? (
                            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                            <source src={this.state.video.blob} type="video/mp4"/>
                          </video>
                        ) : (
                          ""
                        )}
```

console.log(this.state.video) gives me blob url like for example

> blob:http://localhost:3001/c85af256-10f7-4562-9078-e2cae746a8a2

so then in video tag when i set src={this.state.video.blob} it doesnt show a preview and also if i copy paste the link of any online video url like

> "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4"

it works fine